# why is elif statement running indefinitely in python

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

My elif command is running indefinitely. My elif logic is simple. I have two API. 1) USA API- I wanted this API need should work only before year 1985. 2) Australia API- This API works only for year 1985 & after. After that I merge these two dataframe into one dataframe.

**To run this logic we need to write this command in the terminal. You can put any value of longitude, latitude in below command.**

**python test.py -latitude '88' -longitude '75' -startYear '1975' -endYear '2021**

Can anyone one help me out why this elif logic is running indefinitely??? Also, please tell me how to fixed it.

```
import requests
import json
import argparse
import time
import pandas as pd
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
##
#   sample command: python test.py -latitude '' -longitude '' -startYear '' -endYear ''
##
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Process some integers.")
parser.add_argument("-latitude", help="Latitude(Degress)")
parser.add_argument("-longitude", help="Longitude(Degress)")
parser.add_argument("-startYear", help="Start of the Year")
parser.add_argument("-endYear", help="End of the Year")
parser.add_argument("--verbose", help="display processing information")
start = time.time()
def main(latitude,longitude,startYear,endYear,verbose):   
    parameters = {  #Australia API
        "latd": latitude, # [deg]
        "latm": 00, # [deg]
        "lats": 00, # [deg]
        "lond": longitude, # [deg]
        "lonm": 00, # [deg]
        "lons": 00, # [deg]
        "elev" : 00, # [km]
        "year" : None, # [YYYY]
        "month" : '07', # [MM]
        "day": '01', # [DD]
        "Ein": 'D'  # [Model]
    }
    parameters1 = {    #USA API
    'lat1': latitude, # [deg]
    'lon1': longitude, # [deg]
    'model': 'IGRF', # [Model]
    'startYear': None, # [year]
    'startMonth': 7, # [month]
    'startDay':1,  # [date] 
    'resultFormat': 'json', # [format] 
}
    hostname = "https://api.geomagnetism.ga.gov.au/agrf" #Australia API
    hostname1 = "http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag-web/calculators/calculateDeclination?%s"  #USA API
    df_1=pd.DataFrame()
    df_2=pd.DataFrame()
    for year in range(startYear, endYear): 
        if endYear < 1985:
            if  startYear < 1985:        
                print('Good, this loop working')        
        elif startYear < 1985:  # Loop is running indefinetly
            for year in range(startYear, 1985): #USA API
                try:
                    parameters1["year"] = year      #USA API
                    response = requests.get(hostname1, params= dict(parameters1, ps=str(year)))
                    # extract JSON payload of response as Python dictionary
                    json_payload = response.json()
                    # raise an Exception if we encoutnered any HTTP error codes like 404
                    response.raise_for_status()
                except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
                    # handle any typo errors in url or endpoint, or just patchy internet connection
                    print(e)
                except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
                    # handle HTTP error codes in the response
                    print(e, json_payload['error'])
                except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                    # general error handling
                    print(e, json_payload['error'])
                else:
                    json_payload = response.json()
                    #print(json.dumps(json_payload, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
                    df = pd.DataFrame(json_payload['result'])
                    new_row = {
                        "SourceFile": hostname1,
                        "Year": year,
                        "Magnetic Declination": df.iloc[0, 2],
                        "Latitude": -35,
                        "Longitude": 145
                    }
                    df_1 = df_1.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
                    df_1 = df_1[['Year', 'Latitude', 'Longitude','Magnetic Declination','SourceFile']]
                    df_1.to_csv('magnetic_declination_usa.csv',index=False)  

                    for year in range(1985, endYear):
                        try:     #Australia API
                            parameters["year"] = year
                            response = requests.get(hostname, params= dict(parameters, ps=str(year)))
                            # extract JSON payload of response as Python dictionary
                            json_payload = response.json()
                            # raise an Exception if we encoutnered any HTTP error codes like 404
                            response.raise_for_status()
                        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
                            # handle any typo errors in url or endpoint, or just patchy internet connection
                            print(e)
                        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
                            # handle HTTP error codes in the response
                            print(e, json_payload['error'])
                        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                            # general error handling
                            print(e, json_payload['error'])
                        else:
                            json_payload = response.json()
                            #print(json.dumps(json_payload, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
                            df = pd.DataFrame(json_payload)
                            new_row = {
                                "SourceFile": hostname,
                                "Year": year,
                                "Magnetic Declination": df.iloc[5, 3],
                                "Latitude": latitude,
                                "Longitude": longitude
                            }
                            df_2 = df_2.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
                            df_2 = df_2[['Year', 'Latitude', 'Longitude','Magnetic Declination','SourceFile']]
                            df_2["Magnetic Declination"] = df_2["Magnetic Declination"].apply(lambda x: x.replace(" deg", ""))
                            df_2.to_csv('magnetic_declination_australia.csv',index=False)

                df_3 = pd.concat([df_1,df_2], axis=0)            #Merge dataframe into one    
                df_3.to_csv('Magnetic_Declination_(USA+Australia).csv',index=False) 

        else:    # Case where endYear < 1985 and startYear > 1985 (probably an input error)
            print("Invalid Year. Please check the startYear & EndYear.")
                                               
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    latitude = args.latitude
    longitude = args.longitude
    startYear = int(args.startYear)
    endYear = int(args.endYear)
    verbose = args.verbose
    main(latitude,longitude,startYear,endYear,verbose)  # Calling Main Function
    print("Processed time:", time.time() - start)  # Total Time
```

Comment: What arguments do you run it with when you expect the elif not to happen?

Answer (score 1):

It is running forever, because you use the variable `year` inside the loop again in a loop. This is causing a side-effect that keeps your loop busy :-) Use different variable names when nesting for loops.